# submit form based on location on page load

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a drop down menu that I am using as selector for the country to view our locations.

The drop down is currently working but I want it to load users current country before they have to select it from the drop down so that it automatically shows them the listing of locations in their country.

Currently I have the dropdown retrieving the users country however it is not submitting the form it is only showing the "selected" value.

Here is my code including the sql:

```
<?php

require_once( DIR_WS_CLASSES . 'geoplugin.class.php');
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();

echo $geoplugin->countryCode;

echo $geoplugin->countryName;

?>
<div style="padding:80px 0 20px 20px;border-bottom:1px solid #a6a6a6; ">
<h1 style="color:#000"><?php echo LOCATION_TITLE ;?></h1>
</div>

<div style="padding:20px 0px 0px 1%;">
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post"  >

    <select name="selectboxvalue" onchange="this.form.submit();" id="selectboxvalue"   >

        <option>SELECT A COUNTRY</option>
        <option value="<?php $geoplugin->countryCode; ?>" <?php if ($geoplugin->countryCode == 'US' || $_POST["selectboxvalue"]=="US" ) echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>USA</option>
        <option value="canada" <?php if ( $geoplugin->countryCode == 'CA'|| $_POST["selectboxvalue"]=="canada" ) echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Canada</option>
        <option value="international" <?php if ( $_POST["selectboxvalue"]=="international" ) echo "selected"; ?>> International</option>
    </select>

</form>
</div>
<?php




$location_query_raw =  "select l.storetitle,l.storeimage, l.country, l.state, l.city, l.postal, l.address, l.phone, l.storelink, l.latitude,l.longitude, l.sortorder, l.status from locations l";


switch ($_POST['selectboxvalue']) {
    case "US":
        $location_query_raw .= "  where l.country like \"%USA%\" ORDER BY l.state ";
        break;
    case "canada":
        $location_query_raw .= " where l.country like \"%CA%\" ORDER BY l.state";
        break;
    case "international":
        $location_query_raw .= " where l.country not like \"%USA%\" and l.country not like \"%CA%\" ORDER BY l.state";
        break;
    default:
        $location_query_raw .= " order by l.state";
        break;
}

$location_query= tep_db_query( $location_query_raw);
```

Comment: Any error in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem... you aren't echoing the value.. :-)

```
<option value="<?php $geoplugin->countryCode; ?>"
```

Just add the echo and now the value will post! :

```
<option value="<?php echo $geoplugin->countryCode; ?>"
```